# Eigenvalues of $A + \mu I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Strang's Linear Algebra 4th edition, page 306, example 6.2B asks to find the eigenvalues of the following matrix:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}5&&&\\&5&\\&&5\\&&&5\\\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}4&-1&-1&-1\\-1&4&-1&-1\\-1&-1&4&-1\\-1&-1&-1&4\\\end{bmatrix} $$

I understand why the eigenvalues of the first matrix are $\{5,5,5,5\}$ and of the second are $\{4,0,0,0\}$.

But then he finds the eigenvalues of $A$ by pairwise subtracting them, resulting in $\{1,5,5,5\}$.

Why could he do that? Previously in the chapter he wrote: "...the eigenvalues of $A + B$ are generally not $\lambda + \beta$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that in this case you're not adding just any matrices: one of them is a multiple of the identity.  $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $A - \lambda I$ is singular.  So this is also equivalent to: $\lambda + \mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A + \mu I$.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. As $A- \lambda I$ being singular says that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, $A + \mu I - \lambda I - \mu I$ being singular says that $\lambda + \mu$ is an eigenvalue for $A + \mu I$.